# Discord.py Game bot not executing a command

Tags: python, discord.py

I am a beginner in python and i am to trying to code a discord game bot in which you have to choose your paths.

I want that the user first run !adv command and then can press 'c' to continue but my code is not able to do so.

I am not getting any error but after running the !adv command ,i am not able to run the 'c' command to further do something.

```
client = discord.Client()



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    general_channel = client.get_channel(864471185907908608)
    await general_channel.send('Hey!')



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    count = 0
    msg = message.content.lower()
    general_channel = client.get_channel(864471185907908608)
    if count == 0:
        if msg == '!adv':
            await general_channel.send('Hello '+ message.author.name +'. \nWelcome to the Lands of The Supreme Lord , The Godfather.\nYou woke up in the marketplace with crowd bustling everywhere.\nYou have many questions.\nWhat led you to this place and whats your destiny?\nYou are set to write your own path here.\nPress c to continue.')
        count += 1
    
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    
    if count == 1:
        if msg == 'c':
            await general_channel.send('\nYou see a vase shop and an weaponsmith ahead.\nDecide who you want to talk.\nType v or w')
```

Please include the code for the solution as well because it is easy to understand with code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really have more than one `on_message` (though you're not registering the second one as an event). To wait for a user response you should use [`client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    def check(m):  # simple check to wait for the correct user
        return m.author == message.author and m.channel == message.channel

    count = 0
    msg = message.content.lower()
    general_channel = client.get_channel(864471185907908608)

    if count == 0:
        if msg == '!adv':
            await general_channel.send('Hello '+ message.author.name +'. \nWelcome to the Lands of The Supreme Lord , The Godfather.\nYou woke up in the marketplace with crowd bustling everywhere.\nYou have many questions.\nWhat led you to this place and whats your destiny?\nYou are set to write your own path here.\nPress c to continue.')

            # Waiting for the response
            resp = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
            if resp.content.lower() == "c":
                # continue the story           
                await general_channel.send('\nYou see a vase shop and an weaponsmith ahead.\nDecide who you want to talk.\nType v or w')

                resp2 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
                if resp2.content.lower() in ["v", "w"]:
                    # continue the story
                    ...

        count += 1
```

You might wanna use some `return` statements to not have such deep indentation.

Comment: Can you please show how i can continue the story ?

Comment: It's pretty much the same as in the code snippet in the answer. `resp = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)` -- this waits for a user to reply. Use that to wait for an answer, then `resp.content` to get the actual content of the message.

Comment: Where exactly? Are you able to fix that by yourself? If not -- please give me the full traceback

Comment: Please add the next part because i am having troublen understanding the problem and the code will really help.

Comment: You're supposed to copy and paste two lines, it's not that difficult. But alright, editing the answer... You should learn more python before diving into `discord.py`, it's not a library meant for beginners.

Comment: Ohk please help me with this problem , i will surely consider learning more about python.

Comment: Alright, we’ll I’ve edited the answer, feel free to check it out. Remember to accept the answer if it helped